# How to get multiple pages table like next page in one sheet in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, lambda, import, google-query-language

How to get 4231 row wise data in 424 pages like next page in one sheet in google sheet.

1 page only fetch 25 rows. in same URL

Total row result found = 4231 results found and  showing total page 1 of 424.

URL: https://www.screener.in/screens/41109/all-stocks/?limit=10&page=1

I use this formula to get only 25 records

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.screener.in/screens/41109/all-stocks/%22,%22table")
```

Screenshot - 1
[screenshot already got result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8geW.png)

Problem and I get solution screenshot

How to fetch 4231 data in 424 pages in one sheet

Screenshot - 2
[Error and get solution screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1AIX.png)

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(REDUCE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://screener.in/screens/41109/all-stocks", "table"), 1), 
 SEQUENCE(10), LAMBDA(x, y, {x; 
 IMPORTHTML("https://screener.in/screens/41109/all-stocks/?limit=25&page="&y, "table")})), 
 "where Col1 matches '[0-9]+'", 1)
```

where 10 is pages

[image]

Comment: **Only Fetch Sequence 88 and (2200) Value.**     `=QUERY(REDUCE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://screener.in/screens/41109/all-stocks", "table"), 1), 
SEQUENCE(88 -N ("number of pages")), LAMBDA(x, y, {x; IFERROR(
IMPORTHTML("https://screener.in/screens/41109/all-stocks/?limit=25&page="&y, "table"),
IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1, 11)/0))})), 
 "where Col1 matches '[0-9]+'", 1)`

Comment: **SHOW Error
In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.**