# Use importHTML and get multiple table with all next page in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Asked this same question before and got it answered and works well too.

Please read this thread : [How to get multiple pages table like next page in one sheet in google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74913256/how-to-get-multiple-pages-table-like-next-page-in-one-sheet-in-google-sheet)

@[player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) Thank You so much for this answer. Still good if I get good data.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This formula works very well. But few data comes. Its complete data is not coming. Because this link has more than 4000 data. And there are about 170 pages in this link.

You can add corrections to this formula or you can create a new formula and give it to me. And I hope to get easily good data.

```
=QUERY(REDUCE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks", "table"), 1), 
SEQUENCE(5 -N ("number of pages")), LAMBDA(x, y, {x; IFERROR(
IMPORTHTML("https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks/?limit=25&page="&y, "table"),
IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1, 11)/0))})), 
 "where Col1 matches '[0-9]+'", 1)
```

1. If I write sequence 5, the result comes.

[image]

2. If I write sequence 170 and above, the result comes like this. and

Error show **: #VALUE -** In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

[image]

This has been tried in Google Sheets and you can do it too.

Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yawdkBHkheaXeziWHFBFd3gngO3EQJr0d19lUH9cVfI/edit?usp=sharing

I have all the data from this link ie more than 4000 data. And there are about 170 pages. I hope to get more and more data easily.

URL : https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks/

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is most likely because you are trying to fetch **170** pages while the [source page](https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks/) tells *Showing page 1 of **169***.  You should use an end page number that is no larger than 169.

You may also want to retrieve the data in smaller chunks. You can specify the start and end pages with this remix of player0's formula:

```
=arrayformula( 
  lambda( 
    baseUrl, pageStart, pageEnd, 
    query( 
      reduce( 
        importhtml(baseUrl & pageStart, "table"), 
        sequence(pageEnd - pageStart, 1, pageStart + 1), 
        lambda( 
          result, pageNumber, 
          { 
            result; 
            iferror( 
              importhtml(baseUrl & pageNumber, "table"), 
              iferror(sequence(1, 11) / 0) 
            ) 
          } 
        ) 
      ), 
      "where Col1 is not null", 1 
    ) 
  )( 
    "https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks/?limit=25&page=", 1, 150 
  ) 
)
```

Replace the `1` with the start page and the `150` with the end page you want.

Comment: Sir i try but error show. please Execute this formula in the Google Sheet: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yawdkBHkheaXeziWHFBFd3gngO3EQJr0d19lUH9cVfI/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: Error Show - 
Argument 1 of function LAMBDA is not a valid name.

Comment: Sir Please for me is Very Helpful or very important Provide Google Sheet Live Example. Thank You so much Sir.

Comment: The formula I gave you works fine. Your sample spreadsheet is throttling `importhtml()`, giving the error _**Error:**
Loading data may take a while because of the large number of requests. Try to reduce the amount of IMPORTHTML, IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED or IMPORTXML functions across spreadsheets you've created._ You have used too many imports during the past 24 hours.

Comment: To try the formula out, create a new spreadsheet with the [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform). That spreadsheet will be owned by another account that has not exhausted its quota.

Comment: Sir I want the url which formula you have given. In that. I have tried but getting error with #value. You can see this in google sheet.  And try it and give me the formula and try it in the sheet called **URL - Solution** in the google sheet, sir please.  [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yawdkBHkheaXeziWHFBFd3gngO3EQJr0d19lUH9cVfI/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: Sir Just For Example -  company Name - **R J Bio-Tech Ltd** Show URL Result Like **company/536456/**

Comment: The sample spreadsheet you mention has an `importxml()` formula that differs from the `importhtml()` formula you asked about. That is a different question that will require a different solution. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Sir this page has total 170 pages so i fetch the data of 170 pages then i get full data first time and then when i open the sheet again i get 170 page data not showing but less like i entered 170 in formula Page data requested. There is no error but there is a problem in data fetching. Please sir give me some solution to get data of all pages forever. Please sir I am making a personal request to you. That I hope to get the data well in this google sheet [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yawdkBHkheaXeziWHFBFd3gngO3EQJr0d19lUH9cVfI/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: Sir the data i get from this formula is the same data i want through google app script. I am ready to **Money pay** for that. Pls help sir.

Comment: Sir Read this thread : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75073542/scraping-a-table-from-screener-in-using-google-apps-script]

Comment: To hire a Google Apps Script consultant, check out this [register of consultants](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1U1y6Vjf5ClEof15JLw4qg7tpjpo4MHk7uhVKpjVkA9M/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

*Probably*, the results you have so far is due the limit of characters the cell can store and also the way the data is available on the website (*i.e. the data source*).

Also, IMO, for these kind of tasks, consider use Apps Script and/or use proper APIs.

I've added a new sheet called "[SAMPLE_EACH_PAGE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yawdkBHkheaXeziWHFBFd3gngO3EQJr0d19lUH9cVfI/edit#gid=1772207566)" - which contains a sample where I use the following formula:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks", "table",1)
```

and, for every page, add the following formula:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks?page=X", "table",1)
```

where `X` on `page=X` means the page number to get the data.

The catch here is that you need a way to set the formula each certain cells - every 26 or 27 cells if I count correctly.